# Which of these German sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-order, grammaticality, infinitive

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort mit jemanden aufhören kann zu lieben.

or

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort mit jemanden zu lieben aufhören kann.

and my requested meaning in English is "I am not a human than can stop loving someone instantly".

Answer (score 4):

I think this would be better

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der einfach aufhören kann, jemanden zu lieben.

---

Of your two options this one is the closest to correct

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort mit jemanden zu lieben aufhören kann.

Problems arise post-comma, however.

> mit jemanden

*mit* is a dative preposition so one must say

> mit jemandem

In reality, we don't really need that *mit* there because *lieben* is transitive, which means it must take a direct object. Since it's the direct object of *lieben*, *jemand-* becomes *jemanden* in the accusative.

So now our sentence is

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort jemanden zu lieben aufhören kann.

*Der* is a relative pronoun which introduces our appositive, the phrase that describes the antecedent (Mensch) further. But we have things in our appositive that do not describe *Mensch* but rather tell what *ich*, the subject does. Those things namely are...

> jemanden zu lieben

I love someone but that however does not shed any light onto what that *Mensch* is doing. So it has no place in our appositive (it goes outside the commas behind the appositive). Hence our sentence is now...

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort aufhören kann, jemanden zu lieben.

Our work is almost finished! It was previously mentioned earlier that *einfach* works better in this sentence than *sofort* stylistically and connotation-wise. So our final product is...

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der einfach aufhören kann, jemanden zu lieben.

Comment: To fit in the "mit" it would also be possible to say "Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort damit aufhören kann, jemanden zu lieben" but your translation is better.

Comment: This might be better, but it is dodging the question. There is *always* a better rewording, but if the question is about A vs. B, then A vs. B is what we should try to address. *Then* we can go ahead and suggest C, though again, it should be made clear *why* C is better than either A or B. Otherwise it's hard to learn anything from it. It's giving a man a fish rather than teaching him fishing.

Comment: I see what you mean! I added a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The *mit* is inappropriate – strictly, you are suggesting that you’re not a person who can stop loving with somebody.

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort aufhören kann, jemanden zu lieben.

This is one step better, but it’s still awkward. »Ich bin kein Mensch« is a slightly clumsy formulation – correct, but you’d never hear a native speaker use it.

> Ich kann nicht einfach aufhören, jemanden zu lieben.

Finally, something better. The best, though, would be to say

> Ich kann nicht einfach aufhören zu lieben.

Every language has a logic, and German has a lot of it. A language, to get all Sapir–Whorf, conditions how you think by conditioning how you can express the same idea. Thus, while the second translation is ok, I think the last one gets it across much better (unless you want to put very specific weight on *someone,* in which case, however, you might feel you want to define that term).

Answer (score -1):

I would choose the first sentence which is

> Ich bin kein Mensch, der sofort mit jemandem aufhören kann zu lieben.

because the verb *aufhören* is one of the "*zu* construction verbs" that means the preposition *zu* is needed. And instead of *jemanden*, it's *jemandem* because *mit* takes the dative case.

Comment: However, the *mit* does not belong there at all.

Comment: Oops, you're right i oversaw that one :)

Comment: So the best to write this sentence is: "Ich bin kein Mensch, der einfach damit aufhören kann, jemanden zu lieben" isn't it?

Comment: No ' damit'  because you already elaborated your sentence. Wait for another native speaker and see what he thinks about it.

Comment: @Khaled.. your suggestion n the comment is possible and fully correct but the one suggested in the other answer is better because it is shorter, more elegant and closer to the original grammatically

Comment: Just to make it clear. The sentence as given here in the answer is incorrect. Your explanations are correct (mit + dative) and this sentence appears grammatically OK but "mit jemandem aufhören zu lieben" is not proper German.